# How to make overflow-y operate independently of overflow-x

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on some CSS for a navigation bar, and I need to use a `max-height` and `overflow-y: scroll` for the dropdown in order to make sure it will fit on the page. However, whenever I set the `overflow-y` property to scroll, it seems to automatically enforce that `overflow-x` must also be set to `scroll`, and as a result, submenus become hidden.

See the jsfiddle below for a working example

https://jsfiddle.net/5eyveyfz/

EDIT: I should clarify the use of my fiddle. The issue arises when you hover over the menu item titled "SubMenu 1" which shows the submenu in question. The expected behavior is that this submenu is visible without a scrollbar, but instead its behaving as though `overflow-x` was set to `scroll`

Comment: I do not see a horizontal scrollbar in your fiddle. Maybe I am not understanding your question correctly

Comment: @MichaelMcCoy, see my edit, the behavior occurs on trying to open the submenu by hovering over the menu item "SubMenu1"

Comment: @epascarello yes, why would you think it isn't? the jQuery parts are functioning exactly as expected, its the CSS that is giving me trouble

Comment: @epascarello , are you sure its not just that you can't see it because its being hidden by the horizontal scrolling behavior? after all, that's the issue in question

Comment: See My answer for some adjustments you can make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing these values will show the dropdown directly below the submenu heading:

```
#menu > ul { 
 overflow-y:scroll;
 overflow-x:hidden;
 max-height:300px;
}

.submenu {
 position:relative;
 display: none;
 left:0; 
 top:0;
}
```

If you want to keep the left position you will need to make the container wider or change it to display:inline-block; without a width set for it to adjust to the size of the content.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not doing this in your fiddle - is it possible the data you are populating in your actual build is forcing the table to overflow its width?

If so, change the container to overflow-x:hidden; in order to prevent the horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I'm not being clear. The issue, is that the submenu, triggered by hovering over the  "SubMenu1" item, is being hidden because the behavior is being set to `scroll` when It is explicitly declared as visible in the css